# cell.Value not retrieving the carriage returns in the cell

Tags: excel, vba, range

My Excel cells have carriage return(s) \ line feeds, but when reading into cell.value, the carriage returns disappear.  Is there a way to handle this so that I can determine where the line breaks were (without modifying my source Excel sheet data)?

In the code below (at the bottom of this thread), I would have expected the ProductText variable to be set as:

```
Orange<CR> 
Red<CR>
Yellow<CR>
```

where `<cr>` means carriage return.

I can confirm that the line-feeds are present when I copy from an Excel cell into Notepad.

But in VBA, `ProductText` is populated as: "Orange Red Yellow" and the carriage returns are gone.

```
'YOU MAY SKIP TO THE ******************************************* for the purposes of this post

Public Sub ProcessCharmMingFile(Excel_UNC_Path As String)

    Dim src As Workbook

    Dim ProdPushWorkbook As Workbook

    Set ProdPushWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook


    Set src = Workbooks.Open(Excel_UNC_Path, True, True)

    Dim c As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Dim Text As String

    src.Sheets("Table 1").Activate

    src.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    LastRow = src.ActiveSheet.Range("A30000").End(xlUp).Row
    Text = LastRow
    Text = "A1:T" + CStr(Text)

    Set r = Range(Text)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To MaxItems
        PONumber(i) = ""
    Next


    Dim PageCounter As Integer
    PageCounter = 0
    RecordCounter = 0


    Dim ProductText As String
    Dim QtyText As String
    Dim HeatText As String


       '***********************************************************
       '***********************************************************
       '***********************************************************

    For Each c In r
        If c.Value = "ALLIED FITTING Product Code" Then
            PageCounter = PageCounter + 1
            ProductText = c.Offset(1, 0).Value
            HeatText = c.Offset(1, 1).Value
            QtyText = c.Offset(1, 2).Value

        End If
    Next

       '***********************************************************
       '***********************************************************
       '***********************************************************



    If RecordCounter = 0 Then
        Call AbortFileProcessing("No Valid Reoords Dected", False, ProdPushWorkbook)
    End If


    src.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure that the Wrap Text is enabled for the cell.

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").WrapText = True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that you need a Line Feed to get the lines to display separately in a cell.

VBA has the appropriate constants for this:

```
Sub CRLFString()
Dim str As String

str = "hello" & vbCr & "world!"
Range("A1").Value = str 'Reads: "helloworld!" - Wrap Text won't change this.

str = "hello" & vbLf & "world!"
Range("A2").Value = str 

str = "hello" & vbCrLf & "world!"
Range("A3").Value = str 'Both of these read
    'hello
    'world!

End Sub
```

However, if you would output these strings using `Debug.Print` all three of them would be on 2 lines as expected.

In short: Add a line feed, otherwise you get the result described in the question.
You can just use `Replace` on `vbCr` to do so:

```
Sub AddLineBreaksAndOutput(str As String)
    str = Replace(str, vbCr, vbCrLf)
    Range("A4").Value = str
End Sub

Sub Test()
Dim str As String
str = "hello" & vbCr & "world!"
AddLineBreaksAndOutput str
End Sub
```

Comment: can't vote it up, as they won't let me on my poor reputation. but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

### Carriage Return Trouble

Out of curiosity what is the code number of the "CR" character. You can get it using this formula: `=CODE(MID(A1,7,1))` in Excel (adjust `A1` and 7 appropriately).

If this behavior persists you can split the string into an array and concatenate with the appropriate character e.g. Chr(10):

Declare two variables, then after the line ProductText = ... you know what to do.

```
  Dim j As Integer
  Dim vntText As Variant

  ProductText = c.Offset(1, 0).Value
  vntText = Split(ProductText, " ")

  For j = 0 To UBound(vntText)
    If j > 0 Then
      ProductText = ProductText & Chr(10) & vntText(j)
     Else
      ProductText = vntText(0)
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: =CODE(MID(E2,61,1)) = 10, which is a line feed.... still reading all the posts, but I am thinking that i should replace 10 with something else....

Comment: can't vote it up, as they won't let me on my poor reputation. but thank you.

Comment: You can do it some other time without problems. Have some rep.

Answer (score 0):

I want to enhance the answer already posted....

You should replace all types of LF's and CR's with vbCRLF, then use that as your splitter.

Here is my code...  it can be enhanced further, based on your needs.  In my case, it was vbLF that was the culprit, not vbCR.  I replaced both, though, with vbCrLF, and then used that as my splitter...

```
ProductText = Replace(Replace(c.Offset(1, 0).Value, vbCr, vbCrLf), vbLf, vbCrLf)
ProdAry = Split(ProductText, vbCrLf)
```